# How avoid square shape with Laplacian operator in reaction diffusion calculations?

Tags: nonlinear-equations, laplacian, local-coordinates

I have used different variants of the Laplacian operator (div grad) using 4, 8, 12, 20 and 24 of the closest points. I get problems due to the chosen coordinate system and the discretization of the Laplacian operator. See images originating from circular symmetric seeds:

[image: Different Laplacian implementation in reaction diffusion]

It is implemented as https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3sGXWG .

The Laplacian stencils are

[image: Laplacian stencils]

where red points are used in upper left in the first image,

red + green in upper middle,

red + green + blue in upper right,

red + green + blue + orange in lower left box.

red + green + blue + orange + black in lower middle

red + green in is used on lower right with whighting according to [Steven Roberts answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/35604/36580).

The equations don't show the problem but they are

$$
\frac{\partial red}{\partial t} = \nabla^2 red (red + 4 green) \\
\frac{\partial green}{\partial t} = \nabla^2 green (red + 4 green) \\
red := 0.99 red + 0.01 green \\
green := green + 0.05 green(1 - green) - 0.03 red - 0.001 \\
    red < 0: red := max(green, 0)  \\
    green < 0: green:= max(red, 0)  
$$

How can I keep spherical symmetry?

Comment: Can you add the reaction-diffusion problem you are solving with the parameters? It would potentially bring more attention to your question.

Comment: I want stable dots for physics simulations. Circular symmetry should not be broken. Source code is available on the link for those who wish to read.

Comment: People would be reluctant to read your code. It is better to add a mathematical formulation.

Comment: Have you considered deriving a discretization in polar coordinates? Or using a Schwarz-Christoffel transformation to conformally map the circle to the square?

Comment: @JuanM.Bello-Rivas No but I hope I can try but I suspect polar coordinates will only fit well if origo is in the centre of the seed.

Comment: What difference would non local coordinates do, like Fourier transformed coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

There are finite difference stencils specifically designed to have rotational symmetry.  For example, instead of the standard second order stencil
$$
\frac{1}{h^2} \begin{bmatrix}
& 1 & \\
1 & -4 & 1\\
& 1 &
\end{bmatrix}
$$
you can use
$$
\frac{1}{6 h^2} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & 1 \\
4 & -20 & 4 \\
1 & 4 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I first came across this in

Hundsdorfer, Willem, and Jan G. Verwer. Numerical solution of time-dependent advection-diffusion-reaction equations. Vol. 33. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013.

on page 301, but I'm sure it's in other sources as well.

When I tried this out in your shadertoy, it unfortunately didn't resolve your issue, and the pattern looked similar to the ones you provided.  I think the real issue is that the circle produced when you click is not a perfect circle, but an approximation on the finite difference grid.  This initial condition is axially symmetric but not radially symmetric.  Refining the mesh would help, but you cannot exactly represent a circle on a Cartesian grid.  My guess is that these slight approximation errors eventually cause the non-symmetric artifacts.

Comment: I tried this. It is the bottom right in the image. Spectral and randomized are my next hopes.